# How will the travel restrictions in Germany due to COVID-19 affect student visas

Tags: visas, germany, covid-19, student-visas

On 16th March, 2020 the EU announced a 30 day travel restriction for all non-essential travel. On 6th April, 2020 Germany has announced the new updated travel restrictions to Germany. However, there is not much clarity for information about students.

Can anybody provide information on what are the restrictions (if any) for people people who need to travel to Germany for their studies (starting summer 2020) on national visa (Type-D)? How will these restrictions affect people, who are about to come to Germany on student visa(s)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think anybody knows what the restrictions will be a month or two from now. The question you should ask is, will your school even be open? If not, there is no point.

Comment: We're not likely to get clarity on future restrictions until the rate of new cases starts dropping significantly. That will certainly be weeks away, possibly months. Frustrating as it is, you'll just have to wait.

Comment: @MichaelHampton currently my school is open and classes are taking place online. However, in the state of my uni (NRW) physical are currently scheduled for 20th April, which I guess may get pushed. However, restrictions are very confusing now. Germany has loosened some restrictions in today's conference.

Answer (score 3):

At present there are to many unknowns to give a reliable answer.

Assuming that the present restrictions remain until September:

- a D-Visa will be required

  - which is what a Student Visa is
- the Universities will be opened up in some form allowing new students to start

taking up residence would probably be considered a valid reason.

A quarantine period of 14 days, being introduced on the 10th of April, must be fulfilled.